# Можно ли как то ускорить Angular2+ ssr?

Tags: angular2, angular

Всем привет. вообщем пишу на Angular 7. Прицепил Universal, все сборки настроены и работают. Для меня было конечно горе решать все конфликты когда делал продакшн под ssr... в проекте довольно много плагинов.... googlemap, swiper, paperjs, textmask, perfectscroll, tweenmax... ну вообщем их достаточно. Когда начал смотреть в нетворках за сколько мне отдается продакшн версия мой показытель был domContentLoaded 1.7s Load 2.2s. мне стало интересно, что будет если я вообще уберу все страницы и оставлю только главную и на ней swiper(раньше на этой странице был paper.js + 2 канваса)...
domContentLoaded 1.5s Load 1.9s.

структура папок dist

```
dist 
  /browser
  /server 
  server.js
```

Размеры файлов значительно уменьшились допустим dist/server/main.js был 900кб ? а после удаления всего стал 200кб. Но результата это не дало, хотя залез в него я увидел (когда он весил 900кб) что там все все либы которые вообще есть в проекте :). Тут еще один вопрос возник, а можно в зависимости от роутинга запрашивать либу? то как то получается что есть lazyModules и подгружаются в зависимости от роута, но сами все библиотеки грузятся сразу...

Подскажите пожалуйста. От чего вообще зависит этот показатель и как я могу на него повлиять. Взял конечно чистую сборку Anular Universal Starter и показатель стал после 2рой перезагрузки domContentLoaded 0.4s

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Производительность SSR в Angular зависит от многих факторов. Например от того, что вы используете на сервере, если это `@nguniversal/express-engine` - выкидывайте его сразу. Метод `renderModuleFactory` возвращает `Promise`, для работы с `Promise` отлично подходит `koa`, поэтому советую вам перейти на этот фреймворк, а еще лучше это сервер без фреймворков, сделать все нативно через `http` пакет, также использовать `nginx` для статики.

Если у вас много сторонних плагинов, то вам нужно чанкировать эти плагины в разные файлы, а не запихивать в один бандл, под чанкированием я подразумеваю динамический импорт:

```
// Плохо
import 'paper';

// Хорошо
import('paper').then(() => {
});
```

Любую работу с плагинами нужно вести вне зоны Angular, зоны на сервере (`zone-node`) также влияют на производительность, работу с любым сторонним плагином обязательно оборачивать в `runOutsideAngular`:

```
class Component implements AfterViewInit {
    constructor(private zone: NgZone) {}

    public ngAfterViewInit(): void {
        this.zone.runOutsideAngular(() => {
            import('swiper').then((Swiper) => {
                new Swiper('.some-class');
            });
        });
    }
}
```

Далее использовать кеширование и резолверы, резолверы (определители) - это сервисы, которые позволяют грузить данные на определенном этапе жизненного цикла роутинга до инициализации компонента. Для кеширования использовать `TransferState`. Например у нас где-то в базе лежат события (конференции, митинги и тд.), нам нужно загрузить это 1 раз и закешировать, чтобы не грузить несколько раз на клиенте:

```
import { Injectable, Inject, PLATFORM_ID } from '@angular/core';
import { Resolve } from '@angular/router';
import { isPlatformServer } from '@angular/common';
import { TransferState, makeStateKey } from '@angular/platform-browser';

import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { tap } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Injectable()
export class EventsResolver implements Resolve<Event[]> {
    constructor(
        @Inject(PLATFORM_ID) private platformId: Object,
        private state: TransferState,
        private eventsService: EventsService
    ) {}

    public resolve(): Observable<Event[]> | Event[] {
        const key = makeStateKey<Event[]>('events');

        if (isPlatformServer(this.platformId)) {
            return this.eventsService.getEvents().pipe(
                tap((events) => this.state.set(key, events))
            );
        }

        return this.state.get(key, []);
    }
}
```

`TransferState` создаст элемент `script`, куда в `innerHTML` будет запихивать `JSON.stringify({ [key]: events })`. Резолвер нужно добавить в провайдеры модуля:

```
@NgModule({
    imports: [EventsRouterModule],
    providers: [EventsResolver]
})
export class EventsModule {}
```

А также в свойство `resolve` типа `Route`:

```
import { ModuleWithProviders } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

import { EventsComponent } from './events.component';

import { EventsResolver } from './events.resolver';

const routes: Routes = [{
    path: '',
    component: EventsComponent,
    resolve: {
        events: EventsResolver
    }
}];

export const EventsRouterModule: ModuleWithProviders<RouterModule> = RouterModule.forChild(routes);
```

Теперь, благодаря резолверу, можно в конструкторе уже получить список наших событий:

```
class EventsComponent {
    constructor(route: ActivatedRoute) {
        console.log(route.snapshot.data.events);
    }
}
```

Также не забывайте про ручную сборку через `webpack`. `webpack 4` в продакшн моде проведет больше оптимизаций и удалит неиспользуемый код.

Comment: простите, думал еще будут ответы. Ваш ответ довольно содержательный сразу отмечу отвеченным. Насчет импорта в хуке ngAfterViewInit очень хорошая идея, но у меня карты googlemap от модуля agm и они импортируются  из @ngModule т.е. соответственно это уже не в компоненте. в  итоге вылетает ошибка при билде 'agm?info-window' cant import ..... from rxjs .... я пытался как то исколючить эту библиотеку, но что то не вышло. Только помог плагин webpack-node-externals в котором я whitelist прописал на agm

Comment: ммм, попробуйте не использовать ангуляровскую обертку, а нативно все сделать, `webpack-node-externals` работает только для нодовских пакетов, соответственно на клиентские пакеты он не обращает внимания, либо же используйте загрузку по требованию, чтобы эта либа шла в отдельный файл с модулем где она используется

Comment: У меня при компиляции серверных файлов не понимал import export... т.е. нода не понимала. Даже я с эксперементальным флагом пробовал. а вы пробовали вешать нативные гугл карты? Все хорошо получалось?